# how to show radiogroup not clicked

Tags: java, android, button

I want to do a Quiz in Android App.

I did a `RadioGroup` to show the answers for every question. I want to show when the `RadioButton`, that represents the answer, isn't clicked, but it's not working fine.

Following my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    int ans;
    private Button btnSubmitQuiz;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        RadioGroup champ=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        champ.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.answer1A:
                    ans1 =0;
                    break;
                    case R.id.answer1B:
                    ans1 =1;
                    break;
                    default:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break; 
                }
            }

        });
}
```

The file .xml is this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/answer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer1A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/answer1B"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

move your Toast message to the "case block" that contains the wrong answer(s)

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId) {
                case R.id.answer1A:
                ans1 =0;
                break;
                case R.id.answer1B:
                ans1 =1;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            }
        }

    });}
```

assume R.id.answr1B holding the wrong answer

Comment: But I want the error message when no button is clicked